# Remove word wrap

Tags: paw-app

Hey how can I remove the word wrap in Paw? For instance, this is what I'm seeing:

[image]

I would like for those `url`'s to not wrap, makes it easier to read. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncheck Preferences > Formatting > Text: Wrap Lines.